# how to retrieve all my Subscriptions channels on youtube using java

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i'm working on a project using youtube api v3 and i want to get Subscriptions like name; id ; etc..... i'm using java and when i tried to modify the code that comes with samples addsubscription.java i get errors plz help me :(

----------------code------------- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert

what i have add

YouTube.Subscriptions.List gt=youtube.subscriptions().list("id,mine=true");
SubscriptionListResponse get=gt.execute();
-------------------------error------------------------

"message" : "No filter selected. Expected one of: channelId, mySubscribers, id, myRecentSubscribers, mine"

Comment: Try this YouTube.Subscriptions.List subscriptions = youTube.subscriptions().list("snippet").setMine(true);

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `mine` parameter to `true` as seen in [this API explorer example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.list?part=snippet&mine=true&_h=2&) to get your own subscriptions or set the `channelId` parameter to get subscriptions of another channel as seen in [this API explorer example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.list?part=snippet&channelId=UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw&_h=4&) (you must be [properly authorized](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) to do this)